# MySQL - Using JOIN and WHERE to determine average hours

Tags: mysql, sql

I am learning MySQL using a [next.tech course](https://next.tech/) that relies on the [following schema](https://i.imgur.com/Wd5ezgd.png):

[image]

My current task is to find the average number of hours worked on one specific project: the hours are under the **project_employees** database, while the project name (Washington Avenue Barber) is under the **projects** database.

I have attempted to use the JOIN and WHERE functions as follow to try and return the average number of hours worked:

```
SELECT AVG(hours) FROM project_employees
WHERE name = 'Washington Avenue Barber'
JOIN  projects 
ON  project_employees.employee_id = projects.id;
```

However, I receive the following error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near 'JOIN projects ON
>   project_employees.employee_id = projects.id' at line 3

I have tried a number of different functions to try and obtain the correct result, however only the following returns a value and it is incorrect (it should return 381.115555, but the code below returns 743.300003):

```
SELECT AVG(hours) FROM project_employees
JOIN  projects
ON  project_employees.employee_id = projects.id
WHERE name = 'Washington Avenue Barber';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of your SQL query seems to be the main problem behind the first error.

you are doing `SELECT-FROM-WHERE-JOIN`, but the actual sequence should be `SELECT-FROM-JOIN-WHERE`.

Your second query (which is returning a wrong value) has the correct syntax, which is why it returns something.

Secondly, you should be comparing `projects.id` with `project_employees.project_id`, not `project_employees.employee_id`. Therefore, your query should be something like -

```
SELECT AVG(hours) FROM project_employees
JOIN  projects
ON  project_employees.project_id = projects.id
WHERE name = 'Washington Avenue Barber';
```

Answer (score 1):

In the above Query, you are trying to compare employee_id and project_id, i think that might be the issue. Make sure that you are using `JOIN` correctly with attributes.

Thank you for reading!!
Happy Learning!!

Answer (score 1):

The where clause must come after join, not before

Answer (score -1):

You need specific wich join you using, there's INNER,LEFT,RIGHT,FULL,OUTER
So try these

```
SELECT AVG(hours) FROM project_employees
INNER JOIN  projects
ON  project_employees.employee_id = projects.id
WHERE name = 'Washington Avenue Barber';
```