# MySQL - Use GROUP BY and SUM to multiply two columns

Tags: mysql, sql

Following on from an [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59675589/mysql-using-join-and-where-to-determine-average-hours), I am learning MySQL using a [next.tech course](https://next.tech/) that relies on the [following schema](https://i.imgur.com/Wd5ezgd.png):

[image]

My task is to write a query to return for each project:

- The project's name as "Project Name"
- The sum of quantity for all orders as "Job Order Quantity"
- The sum price for all job orders "Job Order Price", and
- The cost of all job orders as "Cost'

I have written the following query that satisfies all the above requirements *except* for the Cost column:

```
SELECT p.name AS 'Project Name',
       SUM(jo.quantity) AS 'Job Order Quantity',
       SUM(jo.price) AS 'Job Order Price',
       SUM(jo.quantity * jo.price) AS 'Cost'
FROM projects p
JOIN job_orders jo ON p.id = jo.project_id
GROUP BY  name;
```

The first project result has a Job Order Quantity of **11790** and Job Order Price of **103617.37**, and the Cost should multiply these two figures to total **1221648793.19**. However, my query returns the figure **14321391.34**.

I am unsure what this latter figure is multiplying, nor how to alter the query so the correct cost figure is returned.

Comment: You're very close, I think you need to multiple the sums of quantity and price, instead you are summing quantity times prices. Change your last select column to `SUM(jo.quantity) * SUM(jo.price) as 'Cost'` and see if that gives you what you expect.

Comment: I think your expected value 1221648793.19 is wrong and has no meaning and your query is actually right. So it is more a matter of how to understand the question than a technical issue. Anyway, if you want to get your expected value it will be ```SUM(jo.quantity) * SUM(jo.price)```

Comment: Yes, this change has produced the correct result - thanks!

Comment: I agree that the desired result is nonsensical. If I buy 1 egg at 20p and 3 apples at 25p each, then the total cost is 95p, not  £1.80 (4 x 45)

Comment: I'm assuming the question is less 'common sense' and more an attempt to show how different SQL functions can work together. Good to know that this multiplication is unlikely to come up in real life though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted by [patrick3853](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8001997/patrick3853) and [Olivier Depriester](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8945026/olivier-depriester) in the comments, the line **SUM(jo.quantity * jo.price)** should instead be **SUM(jo.quantity) * SUM(jo.price)**.

The correct query is as follows:

```
SELECT p.name AS 'Project Name',
       SUM(jo.quantity) AS 'Job Order Quantity',
       SUM(jo.price) AS 'Job Order Price',
       SUM(jo.quantity) * SUM(jo.price) AS 'Cost'
FROM projects p
JOIN job_orders jo ON p.id = jo.project_id
GROUP BY  name;
```

Comment: SUM(jo.price) will **never** give "Job Order Price" until all quantities are 1 (one) !

Answer (score 2):

I do not think your course would expect you to get result of

```
sum(quantity) * sum(price)
```

as the result of such sums multiplied does not have any significance in any kind of calculations, analysis, reporting, etc.

```
sum(quantity * price) group by name
```

is intended to multiply each order's quantity by price and then sum the amount per "Project Name".

In addition, does your course material ask for sum of price?

```
sum(price)
```

will give sum of all price per "Project Name" which again, you can not use productively.

If you could start your post with your learning course's question itself...it will be better. But I would suggest you going through syntax and explanations for "select" before proceeding.

Comment: Unfortunately the dot points were the question I had to resolve. It is an introduction to databases module though, so I'm guessing even though it's a meaningless calculation in practice the idea is to demonstrate some of SQL's key functions.

Comment: Yes. The course material is introducing features through such examples. Fine.