# MySQL - GROUP BY and HAVING to determine spending

Tags: mysql, sql

As per some [earlier questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59675589/mysql-using-join-and-where-to-determine-average-hours) of mine, I am learning MySQL using a [next.tech course](https://next.tech/) that relies on the [following schema](https://i.imgur.com/Wd5ezgd.png):

[image]

The next step of the course is to determine if any employees are overspending on two projects:

[image]

For these two projects, Central Valley Hospital project and Big Money Bank project, I am to return:

- The project's name, as "Project Name"
- The first name and last name of employees who worked on the project, as "First Name" and "Last Name",
- Their total spending (i.e. the cost of their job orders), as "Spending", and
- Filter the results to employees who spent over $10,000,000 on either project, and order results by highest cost to lowest.

I have written the following query, but get the error message as reproduced afterwards. I have attempted to troubleshoot the query but do not understand the reason for this error, nor if there are other mistakes in my query that need adjusting:

```
SELECT p.name AS 'Project Name',
       e.first_name AS 'First Name',
       e.last_name  AS 'Last Name',
       SUM(jo.quantity) * SUM(jo.price) AS 'Spending'
FROM projects p
JOIN job_orders jo ON p.id = jo.project_id
JOIN employees e ON p.id = e.id
GROUP BY  1
HAVING 'Spending' > 10000000
ORDER BY  4 DESC
LIMIT  2;
```

> ERROR 1055 (42000) at line 1: Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in
>   GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column
>   'codeys_construction.e.first_name' which is not functionally dependent
>   on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with
>   sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: Whenever you use aggregate functions, you must group by the remaining columns of your `SELECT` statement which weren't aggregated. In this case, you'll have to `GROUP BY` all 3 columns - `Project Name`, `First Name`, and `Last Name`.

Answer (score 1):

This error is being inflicted, because `First Name` and `Last Name` are not being included in `group by`.

To elaborate, you grouped by project name, and displayed the spending using aggregate function. But then, you need to find the spending `per employee`, which is why you included `first name` and `last name`. However, since these two columns are not included in group by, SQL can not decide which of the first and last names to select among the different names belonging to `project name`.

Try changing your group by clause:

```
GROUP BY  'Project Name', 'First Name', 'Last Name'
```

or

```
Group By 1, 2, 3
```

Just to add, maybe you would need to include the clause

```
where p.name = 'Central Valley Hospital' or p.name = 'Big Money Bank'
```

if you want the results for `the two projects` only.

Comment: Thanks @wookiekim - the query is no longer returning the error message. However, it is also returning no data at all, so presumably I've made a mistake elsewhere in the query! I've attempted to contact Next Tech to see if they have the solution available, and I'll share it here if they do

Comment: you shouldn&#39;t join e.id with p.id. Try joining `e.id` with `jo.employee_id` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You will not get a result(or possibly a wrong result) because JOIN employees e ON p.id = e.id is incorrect, there is no direct relationship between projects and employees. Either add that relationship by adding another join to project_employees before joining employees or since project_employees is redundant join employees to job_orders. As mentioned in another answer your group by should include all non-aggregated fields in the select statetement. Also for readability you should us column names rather than enumerated columns.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT p.name AS ProjectName,
       e.first_name AS FirstName,
       e.last_name  AS LastName,
       SUM(jo.quantity) * SUM(jo.price) AS Spending
FROM projects p JOIN
     job_orders jo
     ON p.id = jo.project_id JOIN
     project_employees pe
     ON pe.project_id = p.id JOIN
     employees e
     ON pe.employee_id = e.id
GROUP BY p.name, e.first_name, e.last_name
HAVING Spending > 10000000
ORDER BY spending DESC
LIMIT 2;
```

Notes:

- This fixes the `JOIN` problem by included `project_employees`.
- Only use single quotes for string and date constants.  Don't use them for column names.  This changes the names so they don't need to be escaped.
- The use of numeric place holders for `order by` and `group by` is being phased out.  I replaced them with explicit references.
- I added the additional `GROUP BY` columns.

That said, I'm not sure that this produces useful results.  If not, I would suggest that you ask *another* question with appropriate sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of the logic you want to implement.

Answer (score 0):

I asked the next.tech moderators for assistance and they provided me with the following query that gave the correct data:

```
SELECT p.name AS 'Project Name',
       e.first_name AS 'First Name',
       e.last_name  AS 'Last Name',
       SUM(jo.quantity) * SUM(jo.price) AS 'Spending'
FROM projects p
JOIN job_orders jo ON p.id = jo.project_id
JOIN employees e ON jo.employee_id = e.id 
WHERE  p.name IN ( 'Big Money Bank', 'Central Valley Hospital' )
GROUP BY  1, 2, 3
HAVING Spending > 10000000
ORDER BY  4 DESC;
```

Apparently where I had gone wrong was as follows:

- As noted by @P.Salmon, I needed to join the **job_orders** and **employees** databases, *not* **employees** and **projects**
- After that query, I needed to use the WHERE query to select 'Big Money Bank' and 'Central Valley Hospital' only
- As noted by @woookiekim, I needed to group multiple columns (i.e. **Group By 1, 2, 3**)
- I did not need to add single quotes around **'Spending'** when applying the HAVING query

Thank you to everyone here who gave assistance!